# google スプレッドシートで、列に保護はかけるが、列幅だけ変更できるようにしたい。

Tags: google-spreadsheet

google スプレッドシートで　ある列に保護はかけたいのですが、保護はかかっていつつも列幅だけ変更できるようにしたいです。
可能でしょうか？
可能であればどのようにすればよいでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

訂正します。ヘルプの内容だとできないみたいです。

以下、[ヘルプの内容](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1218656)です。

> 重要: シートを保護すると、以下の操作ができなくなります。
>
> ・セルの書式設定をロックし、同時にユーザーが入力値を編集できるようにする ・パスワードでデータを保護する
>
> 範囲やシートを保護できるユーザー
>
> スプレッドシートのオーナーである場合: 範囲やシートに対して編集権限を設定できます。 スプレッドシートの編集権限がある場合:
> 範囲やシートに対して編集権限を設定できます。ただし、オーナーの編集権限を削除することはできません。
> スプレッドシートの閲覧権限かコメント書き込み権限がある場合: 変更することはできません。

Comment: 警告を表示するだとデータも書き換えられませんか？

Comment: 警告を出すだけで、データが編集出来てはまずいのですが。データを編集できるユーザーは私だけと仮定してください。列幅は閲覧者は誰でも変えられるようにしたいです。